Expo QR Code Not Working: exp+expo-app URL Not Opening in Expo Go App
I'm trying to run my React Native project using Expo, but I'm encountering issues with the QR code provided by the Metro bundler.
Issue:
Instead of getting the usual exp:// URL with my IP address, I'm seeing this URL format:
› Metro waiting on
exp+todokart-expo-app://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.105%3A8081
› Scan the QR code above to open the project in a development build. Learn more:
https://expo.fyi/start

When I scan the QR code with the Expo Go app on my phone, nothing happens. The project does not open, and there’s no error message. I’m not sure what’s causing this or if I need to configure something differently.
Things I've Tried:

Updated to the latest versions.
Ran npx expo start.
Cleared the Metro cache using expo start -c.
Tried different networks to rule out network issues.

